# Proof that the real number $\text {fin} \mathcal M$ has an additive inverse using induction.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, induction, proof-explanation

This question regards the proof outlined on page 138 of [Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1 Foundations of Mathematics: The Real Number System and Algebra; Edited by H. Behnke, F. Bachmann, K. Fladt, W. Suess and H. Kunle](https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke)  The part giving me trouble is in **bold text**.

In the following $S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$ means the set of upper
bounds of the set $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathbb{Q},$ $\text{fin}\mathcal{M}$ means *the least upper bound of $\mathcal{M},$* (AKA, *finis superior* or *supremum*) and

$$\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\equiv\left\{x+x^{\prime}\vert{x\in{\mathcal{M}}\land x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime}}\right\}.$$

We wish to show
that the real number $\text{fin}\mathcal{M}$ has an inverse.

> For this purpose we consider the set $\mathcal{M}^{\prime}$ of $x^{\prime}$
>   with $-x^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$ and show that $S\left(0\right)\subseteq S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right)$
>   and also $S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right)\subseteq S\left(0\right),$
>   so that $S\left(0\right)=S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right),$
>   and therefore $\text{fin}\mathcal{M}+\text{fin}\mathcal{M}^{\prime}=0,$ as
>   desired.
>
> For the proof of the first inclusion we assume $z\in S\left(0\right),$
>   so that $z\ge0.$ From $x\le-x^{\prime}$ for all $x\in\mathcal{M},$$x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime}$
>   it follows that $x+x^{\prime}\le z,$ so that $z\in S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right).$
>   Thus we have shown $S\left(0\right)\subseteq S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right).$
>
> For the proof of the second inclusion we assume $z\in S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right),$
>   so that $z\ge x+x^{\prime}$ for all $x\in\mathcal{M},$$x\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime},$from
>   which it follows that $z-x^{\prime}\ge x,$ so that $z-x^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right).$
>
> **Since $-x^{\prime}$ is an arbitrary number from $S\left(\mathcal{M}\right),$
>   we can prove by complete induction that $\left(n+1\right)z-x^{\prime}=z+\left(nz-x^{\prime}\right)$
>   implies $nz-x^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$ for all natural
>   numbers $n,$ and then for $x\in\mathcal{M}$ we obtain the result
>   that $n\left(-z\right)\le-\left(x+x^{\prime}\right)$ for all $n.$**
>
> Since the order is Archimedean, it is impossible that $-z>0.$ Thus
>   $z\ge0,$ and we have completed the proof that $S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right)\subseteq S\left(0\right).$

The first part goes as follows:
Assume $z\in S\left(0\right):$

$$
z\in S\left(0\right)\implies z\ge0
$$

$$
\implies\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime}}\left(x\le-x^{\prime}\implies x+x^{\prime}\le z\right)
$$

$$
\implies z\in S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right)
$$

$$
\implies S\left(0\right)\subseteq S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right).
$$

I get hung up on the second part.  This is what I have so far:
Assume $z\in S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right):$

$$
z\in S\left(\mathcal{M}+\mathcal{M}^{\prime}\right)
$$

$$
\implies\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime}}\left(z\ge x+x^{\prime}\implies z-x^{\prime}\ge x\right)
$$

$$
\implies z-x^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)
$$

The second assumption also leads to

$$
\implies\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime}}z-x^{\prime}-x\ge0,
$$

so

$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}^{\prime},n\in\mathbb{N}_{1}}\left(z-x^{\prime}-x\right)^{n}\ge0
$$

Since $-x^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$ we can choose $-x_{1}^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$
such that

$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M}}\left(-x_{1}^{\prime}-x\right)\ge1.
$$

Next we choose $x_{1}$ such that $-x_{1}^{\prime}-x_{1}=1,$ so $\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M}}\left(x_{1}\ge x\right).$
Thus we can find some $-x_{2}^{\prime}\in S\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$
such that $x\le x_{1}<-x_{2}^{\prime}<-x_{1}^{\prime}=1+x_{1}.$

From this we have $z-x_{1}^{\prime}-x_{1}=z+1>z-x_{2}^{\prime}-x_{1}>0.$  Let $\delta=-x_{2}^{\prime}-x_{1}$.

$$
\left(z+1\right)^{n}-\left(z+\delta\right)^{n}>0
$$

$$
\left(1+nz+\dots+z^{n}\right)-\left(\delta^{n}+nz\delta^{n-1}\dots+z^{n}\right)>0
$$

$$
\left(1+nz+\dots\right)-\left(\delta^{n}+nz\delta^{n-1}\dots\right)>0
$$

At some time in the past I learned how to do this very cleanly, but I don't recall how. What is a good way of producing the result indicated in the book?

The way I once knew may have involved setting $z=x^{\prime}+\text{fin}\mathcal{M},$ by an appropriate choice of $x^{\prime}.$

Comment: What is $\text{fin}\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: $\text{fin}\mathcal{M}$ is the *finis superior* or *supremum* of the set $\mathcal{M}$.  Also know as the *least upper bound*.

Comment: figured that but never saw the notation before

Comment: I don't have the book so not sure how addition is defined. Dedekind cuts?

Comment: I've added definitions and a bit of speculation.  If something is still unclear, please let me know.  Thanks for your interest.  And, yet, this pertains to Dedekind cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are right : the proof is quite short and not very clear*.

The author choose $z \in S(\mathcal M + \mathcal M')$, so that $z \ge x + x'$ for all $x \in \mathcal M, x' \in \mathcal M'$.

$z$ is a *rational* whatever, and we want to prove that $z \ge 0$, i.e. that $z \in S(0)$.

From  $z \ge x + x'$ it follows that $z — x' \ge x$, so that $z — x' \in S(\mathcal M)$.

What the author has to prove by induction is that :

> $nz — x' \in S(\mathcal M)$.

Thus, having proved the base case : $z — x' \in S(\mathcal M)$, where $-x' \in S(\mathcal M)$, we have to prove the induction step :

> assuming that $nz — x' \in S(\mathcal M)$, we have to show that :
>
> > $(n + 1)z — x' \in S(\mathcal M)$.

The next step of the proof relies on :

> $(n +1)z — x' = z + (nz — x')$.

By induction hypotheses : $(nz — x') \in S(\mathcal M)$.

But the base case is : $z + (— x') \in S(\mathcal M)$, for $-x'$ whatever in $S(\mathcal M)$. Thus, we have to consider $(nz — x')$ as the $-x'$ and it's done.

---

Having proved $nz -x' \in S(\mathcal M)$, for every $n$, this amounts to : $nz -x' \ge x$, and thus : $nz \ge x+x'$, i.e.

> $n(-z) \le - (x+x')$, for every natural number $n$.

Comment: I will have to go over this a couple more times before I fully accept it.  Your approach is much more direct than the one I was shown long ago.  I haven't completely reconstructed that argument yet, but I believe the essential induction steps turn out to be the same in both approaches.  As you may know, there are no exercises in the chapter, and very few in the entire book.  The book **is** the exercise.  Sometimes subtleties are lost in translation, which can detract from lucidity.  And then we must always consider the limitations of the reader.